# MongoDB - How to return only the items from an array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, aggregation-framework

Data-Structure's Format:

```
[
  {
    "related": [
      {
        "_id": "xxvxcv",
        "price": "5266",
        "title": "Title 1"
      },
      {
        "_id": "fggfd",
        "price": "5266",
        "title": "Title 2"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Now, I want to return only the object from the `related` array.

I want to remove the `related` key and return only the items present in the `related` array.

**Expected output should be like this:**

```
[ 
    {
        "_id": "xxvxcv",
        "price": "5266",
        "title": "Title 1"
      },
      {
        "_id": "fggfd",
        "price": "5266",
        "title": "Title 2"
    }
]
```

What's my aggregation query should be? Any suggestions?

```
db.collection.aggregate([  ..??  ])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/): Deconstructs an array field from the input documents to output a document for each element.

[`$replaceRoot`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/): Replaces the input document with the specified document.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$related"
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: "$related"
    }
  }
])
```

> Output

```
[
  {
    "_id": "xxvxcv",
    "price": "5266",
    "title": "Title 1"
  },
  {
    "_id": "fggfd",
    "price": "5266",
    "title": "Title 2"
  }
]
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/g3VJ6nKo1v_)